# ASA5510 Site-to-site VPN with Bluecoat SSG proxy

Tags: cisco-asa

I have a scenario whereby we will have over 15 remote IPSEC sites concentrated back to HO where a bluecoat proxy lives; the proxy is in transparent mode. The remote sites will have SRP527W's with an ASA5510 at HO. All remote sites have a DSL connection. I'm wondering if we can send across all web traffic from the sites through the bluecoat proxy to enforce content management.

I've had a quick look at the `route inside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 <proxyIP> tunneled` command, but I haven't tested it yet.

Just wondering if anybody has other suggestions?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to redesign a bit of your network to solve this.
Here's the network as I see it:

LAN-BlueCoat-ASA --> VPN --> SRP.

You can transport all traffic from spokes to the ASA, then to Internet, but your proxy is behind ASA so I don't see how the traffic can reach it.
One desperate solution, would be to move the proxy in front of the ASA, but for many reasons I don't recommend it.

This being said, I can think of two ways of doing it:
 - use an explicit proxy to all the remote sites (the bluecoat IP), so everyone will send any WEB request through the tunnel straight to the appliance
 - replace ASA with a VPN&UTM equipment like Fortinet, SRX, UTM-1...